# js() funcion and html characters

Tags: atk4

Im using $this->js(true, 'your js here');, but have a problem:

If certain conditions are met, i redirect page to something else, with js function like this:

```
top.location = "http://some-url.com?param1=AAA&param2=BBBB"
```

but & character converts to: `&amp;`

I know i can use `$this->api->redirect('some-url', array('param1'=>AAA, 'param2'=>BBB));`
But for some reasons i have to use js function, but only to write html characters properly.. How to acomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this:

```
if($condition){

  $this->js(true)->univ()->location('http://some-url.com?param1=AAA&param2=BBBB');

}
```

More information here: http://book.agiletoolkit.org/js/univ.html